# Image returned null,can't be decoded(Android)

Tags: android

I'm doing a Android project and I'm storing the image in database using blob.I keep on getting these errors.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Logcat shows

> 04-30 19:20:39.131: D/AbsListView(13034): onDetachedFromWindow
>
> 04-30 19:20:48.821: D/AbsListView(13034): Get MotionRecognitionManager
>
> 04-30 19:20:52.074: I/Edit Button Clicked(13034): **********
>
> 04-30 19:20:52.154: D/skia(13034): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory
>   returned null

my code to decode`

```
Filenames c = dbHandler.Get_Files(USER_ID);
byte[] image=c.getImage();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length); img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

To encode

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); theImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
imageName = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Why not storing the path to the image instead of the image itself?

Comment: Yes!It worked..Thank you for your suggestion.Can I know why it's better to store the path of the image instead of storing it as blob?

Comment: It is better because you are just storing a string instead of a BLOB.